# make int(1) and int(2) become int(12)

Tags: php, string, integer

I'm trying to manually convert a string to an integer using ord(), not automatically such as (int), intval() or settype().  Are there other ways to convert a string manually?

```
<?php
function first($string){
  for($i=0; $i!=strlen($string); $i++){
  if(ord($string[$i])===46){
    $stop=true;
  }
  if(!isset($stop)){
    $n=ord($string[$i]);
    if($n===48){$n=0;}
    elseif($n===49){$n=1;}
    elseif($n===50){$n=2;}
    elseif($n===51){$n=3;}
    elseif($n===52){$n=4;}
    elseif($n===53){$n=5;}
    elseif($n===54){$n=6;}
    elseif($n===55){$n=7;}
    elseif($n===56){$n=8;}
    elseif($n===57){$n=9;}
    else{ $n=0;}
    var_dump($n);
  }
}
}
first("12"); // result = int(1) int(2), what i want is int(12)
?>
```

Comment: means u want to change string into integer upto 46 number

Comment: What is the use of writing a manual string-to-int conversion? Rewriting this will achieve nothing. If you still really really want to do it, read from left to right and each time you find the next number, multiply the value of your current `int` by 10 and add the next number to it.

Comment: Using the `<pre>` tags is not the normal way to mark code on StackOverfow. Indent by four spaces (or highlight the code and press the `{}` button in the editor) and SO will both format it with fixed-width _and_ do code highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

Example #1:

```
function first($string){
  return $string * 1;
  }
```

Example #2 (calculation of ASCII values of digits):

```
function first($string){
  $res = 0;
  $arr = array_reverse(str_split($string, 1));
  $mult = 1; 
  foreach($arr as $digit) {
    if (ord($digit) > 47 && ord($digit) < 58) {
      $res += (ord($digit) - 48) * $mult;
      $mult *= 10;
      }
    elseif($digit == '-') $res *= -1;
    elseif($digit != '+') {
      $res = 0;
      $mult = 1;
      }
    }  
  return $res;
  }
```

Usage:

```
var_dump(first('-123.534')); // -123
var_dump(first('-1.3'));     // -1
var_dump(first('-777'));     // -777
var_dump(first('12334'));    // 12345
var_dump(first('5.53'));     // 5
var_dump(first('+64.02'));   // 64
```

Comment: But when $string="1.2" it produce int(82) not int(1)

Comment: just one more, if $string="A" it should return int(0) not int(49)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please explain why you want to do this? Homework? There are many many ways to do this and I can't think of anything more complicated (and slow) than yours. Try one of these:

```
function first($string) {
    return (int)$string;
}

function first($string) {
    return intval($string);
}

function first($string) {
    return $string * 1;
}

function first($string) {
    return $string + 0;
}

...
```

**EDIT:** rereading your question, it seems like there could be one or more `.` (ASCII code 46) that aren't decimal points in your input string and you want to find out the "first" part as an int. In this case, simply do:

```
function first($string) {
    return (int)array_shift(explode('.',$string));
}
```

Comment: Can't use (int), intval() or settype(). It's has gonna do with ASCII to solve this, please.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a `$sum` variable separate from `$n`.

Before your `if()` block add:

```
$sum = $sum * 10;
```

And instead of `var_dump($n);` accumulate the interims result there:

```
$sum += $n;
```

Then add `var_dump($sum);` as the *very last thing* in your function. *After* the `if` and `for` block.

Comment: But if the string contain float, it's should be ignored and treat as integer. means $string="1.25" treat as $string="1".

Comment: Use a `break;` rather than `$stop` checks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you would want this, but here is an example how you could do it.

```
<?php
function first($string){
  $n = 0;
  for($i=0; $i!=strlen($string); $i++){
    $n *= 10;
    $o=ord($string[$i]);
    if ($o >= 48 && $o <= 57) {
      $n += $o - 48;
    }
  }
  var_dump($n);
  return $n;
}
?>
```

Comment: first("12"); // it's produce NULL.

Comment: You're right. I corrected the example. But anyway, the solution above is better.